# Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageWriter using request or response?

Tags: odata, odatalib

The class `ODataMessageWriter` in Microsoft.Data.OData.dll, v5.6.1.0 accepts constructors that take `IODataRequestMessage requestMessage` as well as `IODataResponseMessage responseMessage`. The question is when to use one or the other.

I'm implementing a OData service by hand using ODataMessageWriter, and I'd like to get the headers of my response correct based on the headers in the request... but there seems to require a lot of manual coding to get all the headers right (accept, content-type, DataServiceVersion, etc)... Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTTP message you're writing is a response message (i.e., from the server), then you'll use IODataResponseMessage. If you're constructing a message from a client, you'll use IODataRequestMessage. It sounds like you're writing a server, so you should be using IODataResponseMessage when creating writers and IODataRequestMessage when creating readers.

You're right that there's a lot of work involved when using ODataLib directly. ODataLib is great when you want/need to write your own server and need a component that knows how to serialize the OData payload format. If you don't need such a high degree of control over your server, I'd recommend using ASP.Net Web API's OData implementation, which actually uses ODataLib under the hood.

Having said that, ODataLib can figure the Content-Type to respond with if you give it the Accept header from the request. You just need to call SetContentType on the writer settings:

```
var settings = new ODataMessageWriterSettings();
settings.SetContentType(
  "application/json;q=.4, text/html", // Accept
  "iso-8859-5, unicode-1-1;q=0.8"     // Accept-Charset
);
```

Comment: Jen...I was hoping to catch your answer here. I also left you a comment in your great blog. Follow up question: how about dealing with dataserviceversion, min max etc?

Comment: I saw your comment over there too, but this is probably better for hitting a wider audience anyway :) As far as DataServiceVersion, I don't have a simple answer for you. You could keep it relatively simple and always choose to return the highest version you support in DataServiceVersion. It gets compilcated when the client requests a MaxDataServiceVersion lower than the one you support. One way to keep it easy for yourself would be to return an error anytime the user requests a MaxDataServiceVersion lower than what you support (just one idea).

Comment: (Sorry, this is a very brief response -- when I get a chance, I might come back and comment more in detail, but you might want to ask a separate stack overflow question on OData versioning to attract a wider audience)